# Navigate By Columns using Aspose.words in C#

Tags: c#, aspose

Am evaluating the Aspose.words for one of my client, almost all of the feature i have migrated from MS Word library to Aspose.word library. Just one more to go, but am struggling to find the solution for the below:

We have Template document which is in .docx format. Template has a Two column page layout. at run time system would copy paste the content from other document to this Template document. still this steps works fine.

When i open the template page it looks good with 2 column layout.

But we have some logic that should read the last line of First Column & checks whether the text is in specific format, if it is then moves one line down which would automaticaly moves to the next column.

This logic is easily acheivable in Word but i couldn't find any refference in Aspose.words to implement this.

Also i tried to find different option by convering the document to Xml. & found that there is one node called . but this node is visble only when i save the document as xml From Microsoft word. Not occurs if i save the document as xml from Aspose.words.

Please advice me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Gunasekara S

Comment: Hi Guna,
A related query is also answered over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685686/read-last-line-from-first-column-using-aspose-words-v13-1-0   please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

we just have finished integrating a feature into Aspose.Words to open up access to the rendering engine so that each element of the rendered document can be read as it appears as pages, columns, lines, spans etc. This functionality is exactly what you need and will be available in the next version of Aspose.Words which is expected to release in about a week's time. Soon I will be sharing the code snippet to accomplish your requirement.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.